# laravel backend page not found

Tags: laravel, vue.js

This is vuejs and laravel project. I am facing issue in backend when I type complete url with admin then it says not found. This is happening because I was getting 404 laravel error in refresh inside components. So I used the below route in web.php

```
Route::get('/{any?}', function () {
   return view('index');
});
```

In Vuejs, I am using the following:

1. I am using webhistory in route
2. I am also using fallback route

```
{
    path: "/:pathMatch(.*)",
    name: "NotFound",
    component: NotFound,
  },
```

3. backend is based on laravel. Here is the `.htaccess` data

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

4. laravel route
   I tried the below one:

```
Route::get('/{any?}', function () {
   return view('index');
});
```

and this one also

```
Route::get('/{any}', function(){
   return view('index');//pointing to the index file of the frontend
})->where('any', '.*');

Route::get('/admin',[AdminAuthController::class,'Create'])->name('create.login');
Route::post('/admin/login',[AdminAuthController::class,'Store'])->name('store.login');
```

Please suggest

Comment: try to reorder your route, the `/{any}` should be at bottom most.

Comment: Thank you so much. Its a good learning. Much appreciate it.